# Whats Happening in this for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, try-catch

Im not sure whats going on here... Its messing my program up. Im not sure if its some sort of memory leak or just Eclipse messing up. Any thoughts on whats going on? Heres a snippet of my code and the Console Output

```
String Address; //Address is the first three octets of an ip and "i" is the last

for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++){
        try {
            System.out.println(i);
            Address = Address.concat(String.valueOf(i));
            System.out.println(Address + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
        } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

and the console output:

```
    0
    5.20.86.0
    5.20.86.136
    1
    5.20.86.01
    5.20.86.136
    2
    5.20.86.012
    5.20.86.136
    3
    5.20.86.0123
    5.20.86.136
    4
    5.20.86.01234
    5.20.86.136
    5
    5.20.86.012345
    5.20.86.136
    6
    5.20.86.0123456
    5.20.86.136
    7
    5.20.86.01234567
    5.20.86.136
    8
    5.20.86.012345678
    5.20.86.136
    9
    5.20.86.0123456789
    5.20.86.136
    10
    5.20.86.012345678910
    5.20.86.136
11
5.20.86.01234567891011
5.20.86.136
12
5.20.86.0123456789101112
5.20.86.136
13
5.20.86.012345678910111213
5.20.86.136
14
5.20.86.01234567891011121314
5.20.86.136
15
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415
5.20.86.136
16
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516
5.20.86.136
17
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617
5.20.86.136
18
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718
5.20.86.136
19
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819
5.20.86.136
20
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920
5.20.86.136
21
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021
5.20.86.136
22
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122
5.20.86.136
23
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223
5.20.86.136
24
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324
5.20.86.136
25
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425
5.20.86.136
26
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526
5.20.86.136
27
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627
5.20.86.136
28
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728
5.20.86.136
29
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829
5.20.86.136
30
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930
5.20.86.136
31
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031
5.20.86.136
32
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132
5.20.86.136
33
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233
5.20.86.136
34
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334
5.20.86.136
35
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435
5.20.86.136
36
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536
5.20.86.136
37
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637
5.20.86.136
38
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738
5.20.86.136
39
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839
5.20.86.136
40
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940
5.20.86.136
41
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041
5.20.86.136
42
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142
5.20.86.136
43
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243
5.20.86.136
44
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344
5.20.86.136
45
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445
5.20.86.136
46
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546
5.20.86.136
47
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647
5.20.86.136
48
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748
5.20.86.136
49
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849
5.20.86.136
50
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950
5.20.86.136
51
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051
5.20.86.136
52
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152
5.20.86.136
53
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253
5.20.86.136
54
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354
5.20.86.136
55
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455
5.20.86.136
56
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556
5.20.86.136
57
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657
5.20.86.136
58
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758
5.20.86.136
59
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859
5.20.86.136
60
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960
5.20.86.136
61
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061
5.20.86.136
62
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162
5.20.86.136
63
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263
5.20.86.136
64
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364
5.20.86.136
65
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465
5.20.86.136
66
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566
5.20.86.136
67
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667
5.20.86.136
68
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768
5.20.86.136
69
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869
5.20.86.136
70
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970
5.20.86.136
71
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071
5.20.86.136
72
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172
5.20.86.136
73
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273
5.20.86.136
74
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374
5.20.86.136
75
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475
5.20.86.136
76
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273747576
5.20.86.136
77
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677
5.20.86.136
78
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778
5.20.86.136
79
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273747576777879
5.20.86.136
80
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677787980
5.20.86.136
81
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081
5.20.86.136
82
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273747576777879808182
5.20.86.136
83
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677787980818283
5.20.86.136
84
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384
5.20.86.136
85
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273747576777879808182838485
5.20.86.136
86
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677787980818283848586
5.20.86.136
87
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687
5.20.86.136
88
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273747576777879808182838485868788
5.20.86.136
89
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677787980818283848586878889
5.20.86.136
90
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990
5.20.86.136
91
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273747576777879808182838485868788899091
5.20.86.136
92
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677787980818283848586878889909192
5.20.86.136
93
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293
5.20.86.136
94
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273747576777879808182838485868788899091929394
5.20.86.136
95
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677787980818283848586878889909192939495
5.20.86.136
96
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596
5.20.86.136
97
5.20.86.012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273747576777879808182838485868788899091929394959697
5.20.86.136
98
5.20.86.01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071727374757677787980818283848586878889909192939495969798
5.20.86.136
99
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899
5.20.86.136
100
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100
5.20.86.136
101
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101
5.20.86.136
102
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102
5.20.86.136
103
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103
5.20.86.136
104
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104
5.20.86.136
105
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105
5.20.86.136
106
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106
5.20.86.136
107
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107
5.20.86.136
108
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108
5.20.86.136
109
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109
5.20.86.136
110
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110
5.20.86.136
111
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111
5.20.86.136
112
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112
5.20.86.136
113
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113
5.20.86.136
114
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114
5.20.86.136
115
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115
5.20.86.136
116
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116
5.20.86.136
117
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116117
5.20.86.136
118
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116117118
5.20.86.136
119
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116117118119
5.20.86.136
120
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116117118119120
5.20.86.136
121
5.20.86.0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116117118119120121
5.20.86.136
122
```

AND so on....(I had to delete most of it because it went over the max character limit) but you get the point

EDIT: Well i put these System.out.print's to debug my program and see why it wasn't working and i got this and couldnt figure out any explanation

Comment: ...and what type is `Address`?

Comment: First of all.. What is this code for ? What do you expect to get from it ?

Comment: What else would you expect? Prints the loop index, then your every-growing string, then the host IP address. Does this 256 times.

Comment: this is not off-topic!- since it is a valid programming question. Has a beginner programmer error, but still valid, well formatted, I don't understand why is this downvoted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple:

```
Address = Address.concat(String.valueOf(i));
```

`Address` initailly had a whatever value: 5.20.86.0.

In your for loop you are appending the `i` current value, but you don't delete the previous value!
So it is going to `5.20.86.012345678910`  as `5.20.86.` and `012345678910`  than 012345678910 11 12 13 14 and so on.

I hope it is a good explanation for what is going there. Not sure what would you like to archive, but wan't the question.

Comment: I think you probably want to generate a range of ip address from 5.20.86.0 to 5.20.86.255 , but your code is a bit messy :) store the 3 bytes in a variable: initial 5.20.86. and Address = initialValue.concat(String.valueOf(i));

Comment: Oh MY! derp... thats what happens when i'm up too late doing this kind of stuff, thanks

Comment: @user2644350 pls mark as Accepted, if gave the explanation what you have expected, thanks